# How is one supposed to make sense out of this error?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Invocation details says: "Failure Script compilation failed." It doesn't tell me what file or what line. This is a real productivity impediment.

Develop log is empty.

Monitor log show:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.DmsBlobTrigger2
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.DmsBlobTrigger2 ---> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException : Script compilation failed.
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.CreateFunctionTarget(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionLoader`1.GetFunctionTargetAsync[T](Int32 attemptCount)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.GetFunctionTargetAsync()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.InvokeAsync[TReflected](Object[] arguments)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,Object[] invokeParameters,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameters,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??) 
   End of inner exception
```

Comment: Well, try compiling the same thing in Function emulator ?

Comment: Wouldn't I get the same cryptic error message?

Comment: Do you have a simple repro that causes the unfortunately lacking compilation error message? In the end, we're just getting the compilation error output from the compiler and writing it out.

Comment: Yup. Here it is. Was missing a comma:

public static async Task Run(Stream myBlob, string blobname, TextWriter logBlob TextWriter badBlob, IAsyncCollector<string> emailQueueItem, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)

Comment: I have the same issue the the .csx compiler in the VS developer command-line interface. Is very weak in error messages.  I assume Functions uses the same compiler. Should I perhaps express my disappointment to that group?

Comment: I also wanted to point out that normally when there is a cryptic message in "Monitor", I can find the actual compile error in the Logs panel of "Develop". So perhaps the real issue here is that the log service was not working when I was trying to diagnose this.

Answer (score 1):

This, plus the lack of good intellisense, compile time error checking, and unit testability is why I do not recommend proceeding with the CSX approach. Instead, I would suggest the pre-compiled function approach as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/)

I have done it and never looked back. Makes our function development 100x more productive.

Comment: I have been resisting that path since I figured it would add complexity. Also, I don't understand how I could run and debug locally, as Functions depend upon Azure services.

Comment: Add complexity? If you can create a C# DLL project, then you can do this and gain a ton of advantages. Debugging locally is done by the Azure Functions tooling that is part of the Azure SDK. Unfortunately it isn't compatible for VS2017, but you will still get the command line interface. It is totally worth it.